# Split a list by distinct date

Tags: c#, linq

Another easy one hopefully.

Let's say I have a collection like this:

```
List<DateTime> allDates;
```

I want to turn that into

```
List<List<DateTime>> dividedDates;
```

where each List in 'dividedDates' contains all of the dates in 'allDates' that belong to a distinct year.

Is there a bit of LINQ trickery that my tired mind can't pick out right now?

**Solution**

The Accepted Answer is correct.

Thanks, I don't think I was aware of the 'into' bit of GroupBy and I was trying to use the .GroupBy() sort of methods rather than the SQL like syntax.  And thanks for confirming the ToList() amendment and including it in the Accepted Answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var q  = from date in allDates 
         group date by date.Year into datesByYear
         select datesByYear.ToList();
q.ToList(); //returns List<List<DateTime>>
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my little comment in the Question about the ToList() requirements in case I am wrong :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's the methods form.

```
allDates
  .GroupBy(d => d.Year)
  .Select(g => g.ToList())
  .ToList();
```